# Hyperref in verbose citestyle (Biber) not working

Tags: hyperref, biber

I am using hyperref and Biber's verbose citestyle for the bibliography of my Ph.D thesis. However, the hyperrefs for the bibliography does not seem to be working. Here is my set up :

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !BIB TS-program = biber
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{book}

\usepackage[citestyle=verbose-trad1, 
         bibstyle=verbose,
         dashed=true,
         sorting=nyvt,
         hyperref=true,
         backref=true, % will show where in the text are references cited 
         backrefstyle=three, % Compresses any sequence of three or more consecutive pages to a rang
         firstinits=true] % initials for first and middle names
         {biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliographie.bib}          
@book{maclane1986,
    Address = {New York},
    Author = {Mac Lane, Saunders},
    Date-Added = {2014-10-30 10:22:32 +0100},
    Date-Modified = {2014-10-30 10:23:05 +0100},
    Publisher = {Springer},
    Title = {Mathematics, form and function},
    Year = {1986}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{./bibliographie.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\begin{titlepage}
great title
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents 

\mainmatter

This is the citation that should be hyperrefed : \cite{maclane1986}

\backmatter
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{1em}}  
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And this is what I get:

[image: Reference in the main text that is not hyperrefed]

If, instead, I change the citestyle to (for example) authoryear:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !BIB TS-program = biber
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{book}

\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear, 
         bibstyle=verbose,
         dashed=true,
         sorting=nyvt,
         hyperref=true,
         backref=true, % will show where in the text are references cited 
         backrefstyle=three, % Compresses any sequence of three or more consecutive pages to a rang
         firstinits=true] % initials for first and middle names
         {biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliographie.bib}          
@book{maclane1986,
    Address = {New York},
    Author = {Mac Lane, Saunders},
    Date-Added = {2014-10-30 10:22:32 +0100},
    Date-Modified = {2014-10-30 10:23:05 +0100},
    Publisher = {Springer},
    Title = {Mathematics, form and function},
    Year = {1986}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{./bibliographie.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\begin{titlepage}
great title
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents 

\mainmatter

This is the citation that should be hyperrefed : \cite{maclane1986}

\backmatter
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{1em}}  
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

the hyperref works now fine:

[image: Reference in the main text that is hyperrefed]

Is there something I am doing wrong?

PS: I am new to stackexchange, so sorry if my question is not phrased properly...

Comment: The `verbose` styles are intended for use in situations where the full reference is given e.g. in a footnote rather than merely a pointer to a bibliography. Indeed, one use involves not having a bibliography. So I'm not clear why you want the hyperlink there. Since all of the information is already given, why distract readers with a link which only takes them to a repeat of the same information?

Comment: @cfr: I guess you are right, there is no need to have an hyperlink when the full reference is given. In fact, I have just noticed this only happens when a reference is cited for the first time. For subsequent citations, the abbreviation op.cit appears and there is a hyperlink to the full reference. So everything works well! Thank you for your help.

Comment: (Shameless self-promotion ahead) The answer to [Citing one book twice should show short-title second time](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/231491/35864) deals with the links in the way that it links the first citation to the bibliography and subsequent citations to the first cite.