# Citing one book twice should show short-title second time

Tags: biblatex, citing

I use the following bib-file:

```
@misc{kant2007grundlegung,
  title={Grundlegung zur Metaphysik der Sitten, Kommentar von Christoph Horn, Corinna Mieth und Nico Scarano},
  author={Kant, Immanuel},
  year={2007},
  publisher={Frankfurt am Main: Suhrkamp}
}
```

And following commands in my präamble:

```
\usepackage{hyperref} % For hyperlinks in the PDF
\usepackage{url}       
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblio}
\addbibresource{references/biblio.bib}
```

And later

```
\printbibliography
```

Now if I do \footcite(kant2007grundlegung} more than once, I get this:
[image]

But i would love to get the first \footcite like it is here but the next ones Just like "Immanuel Kant, Grundlegung zur Metaphysik der Sitten" with a hyperref to my references-page. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, with `biblatex`'s `verbose`-flavoured styles the first citation is not hyper-linked, because *it* will serve as an anchor meaning the subsequent cites will link back to this first citation.

We can make the first citation link to the bibliography though using the `bibhyperref` format.

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{kant2007grundlegung,
  title      = {Grundlegung zur Metaphysik der Sitten},
  titleaddon = {Kommentar von Christoph Horn, Corinna Mieth und Nico Scarano},
  author     = {Kant, Immanuel},
  year       = {2007},
  publisher  = {Suhrkamp},
  location   = {Frankfurt am Main},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}}

\begin{document}
Lorem\footcite{kant2007grundlegung} ipsum\footcite{kant2007grundlegung}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

You will notice that I got the short title to appear in subsequent cites by moving the "Kommentar von Christoph Horn, Corinna Mieth und Nico Scarano" bit to the `titleaddon` field, you could have moved it to `subtitle` (the difference being in the formatting: `subtitle` is formatted as if part of the title), or if you insist that `Grundlegung zur Metaphysik der Sitten. Kommentar von Christoph Horn, Corinna Mieth und Nico Scarano` go in the `title` by providing a `shorttitle = {Grundlegung zur Metaphysik der Sitten}`.

I have also separated the publisher and location information.

```
@book{kant2007grundlegung,
  title      = {Grundlegung zur Metaphysik der Sitten},
  titleaddon = {Kommentar von Christoph Horn, Corinna Mieth und Nico Scarano},
  author     = {Kant, Immanuel},
  year       = {2007},
  publisher  = {Suhrkamp},
  location   = {Frankfurt am Main},
}
```